# How do I search a specific user's answers?

Tags: support, answers, search, users

I have a question, that I know was answered by a specific user, but I can't find it via a general search.  Can I narrow my search to that user's responses?  If not, please make it so.

Comment: So you want to see all answers by some user?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `user:USERID` to your search, replacing USERID with their actual user id. View more advanced search options at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to search for something like `questionuser:me answeruser:someone`, to see a user's answers to my questions, without knowing the subject of a question. I guess this isn't possible?

Comment: Has there been any update on the status of what @DannyBeckett said - `questioner:me` `answerer:someone`? I know I'm over 4 years late here, but I didn't want to start a new question.

Comment: @Raystafarian Encountered this over a decade. It's in the link, but to save a click and some browsing - use `is:answer` or `is:question`.

Answer (score -1):

```
user:4228 is:answer how
```

You type this in the search box of Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange.
The results will show the answers from user 4228 (or whichever user ID you want) which has "how" as a word in it. This is an example of keyword searching. You can remove the keyword and it will show all their answers, eg: `user:4228 is:answer`

[image][image]