# Search my own questions and questions of a specific user?

Tags: support, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I search a specific user's answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80832/how-do-i-search-a-specific-users-answers)

Hi there,

THis is probably an easy one but i can't seem to figure it out.

I can search questions using the search box.. But can i search ONLY within my own questions?

And is it possible to search the questions of a specific user.

Any help really appreciated

My question applies to stackoverflow.com

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click usernames, it will put "`user:[user_id]`" ([`user:457172`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457172/martin) for you) in the search box, and add keywords or tags after that and search.