# Allow searching by user name in searches

Tags: support, search, users

As described in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80832/how-do-i-search-a-specific-users-answers), you can search for questions or answers by a user with `user:userid`. Why doesn't it allow searching using the username like `user:Bolt Clock` or `user:[Bolt Clock]` or `user:"Bolt Clock"`? How can I know a user's ID? It would be best if I were able to search using their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a user's ID by going to [the Users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users) and searching for that person. The resulting URL, `https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock`, contains the user ID right after `/users/`.

Additionally, if you navigate to the user's page, you'll notice that the search box is pre-filled with the appropriate limiting query:

[image: user:106224 is in the search box]

Usernames are not unique, so if `user:BoltClock` were allowed and there was more than one person with the name “BoltClock”, it would be ambiguous. One reasonable way to deal with this would be for it to limit your search to any user with that name, but that's not currently done.

Comment: or if you click on the search result (to go the user's profile page), your search box on the top right with be auto-populated with the user's id like "user:137537".

Comment: @doubleDown you beat me to it, I was drawing another freehand circle

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a users name to bring up their profile page their user id is automatically inserted into the search bar on the top right of the page, if you click the search bar and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> it will search for all of that user's questions and answers.

[image]